# GHCi: cannot pattern match over custom type

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching, ghci

I have defined a custom type for vectors of type Int:

```
data Vector = Vector Int Int Int
```

Now I want to define a function to add a vector to another, but somehow the syntax is incorrect, even though its very similar to the one employed in [Learn You a Haskell For Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses).

First try, with prefix notation:

```
    Prelude> let vp :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
    Prelude| vp (Vector a b c) (Vector d e f) = Vector (a+d) (b+e) (c+f)

    <interactive>:33:1: parse error on input ‘vp’
```

Second try, with infix notation:

```
    Prelude> let vp :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
    Prelude| (Vector a b c) `vp` (Vector d e f) = Vector (a+d) (b+e) (c+f)

    <interactive>:35:1: parse error on input ‘(’
```

I'm using GHCI v7.8.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just an indentation error

```
Prelude> data Vector = Vector Int Int Int deriving Show
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let vp :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
Prelude|     vp (Vector a b c) (Vector d e f) = Vector (a + d) (b + e) (c + f)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> vp (Vector 1 2 3) (Vector 4 8 12)
Vector 5 10 15
```

works just fine, and so does

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let vp :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
Prelude|     Vector a b c `vp` Vector d e f = Vector (a + d) (b + e) (c + f)
Prelude| :}
```

Comment: Yup, thanks man. On the other hand, if only GHCi threw indentation errors like python...